# How do I include an external JS lib in a meteor app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a basic bootstrap page set up using the  Meteor JS framework.

I've followed this tutorial:

http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way

I want to use Jcrop (an external JS lib):

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

In the bootstrap file I only need to include the body element and the content.  How do I include this JS source, and any other required lib?  Usually I'd just reference the lib in the html page.  Does Meteor magically handle this in some way?

Thanks again in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JCrop you can use meteorite to add it in:

```
mrt add jquery-jcrop
```

If you cant find the package on [atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com/) you can add the files into a folder in `/client/compatibility`. It's usually simple if you have a minified file. This directory is slightly special, since Meteor won't apply variable scoping to files in it.

For others with multiple files, file loading order is important and you would have to make a [package for](http://www.vintyge.com/blog/2012/12/creating-a-basic-meteorite-smart-package) it.

Meteor will automatically reference the file so you can just start using it. For most Jquery plugins, such as JCrop, you can use the Template's [rendered callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) to instantiate the element on the template.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you :) .... This might be easier than I originally thought!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `mrt`. I've used this package before and it worked like a charm.

```
mrt add jquery-jcrop
```

Otherwise, you can download jcrop and put `jquery.Jcrop.min.js` somewhere in your source tree. Meteor will automatically create the script tag for you so you do not need to change your html.

The only trick is making sure that its dependencies are loaded, which is what the `mrt` package does.

Comment: Thanks again Neil!  Looks like Meteor will save me a great deal of time!  Hopefully my app will functionally work after a bit of work!